# Firebase read/ save Data to use it as a list | Swift/Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I have The Following Problem,
I want to save my data to my realtime Database so, that I can use it as a list.

[image: Now It is like this]

so know I am trying to save the PartyId (yellow) with a uuid (red), but this is not really working, because I need the uuid to use it on swift.

So are there probably any other ways to save or read the data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you need the uuid for? How do you plan to use it on swift?

Comment: That’s the point, I don’t need it, I just need the yellow one, but i don’t know how to save it the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to store the data in an array, you need to add the index of the element as a key, and the PartyId as the value.

[image: database structure]

This make the "Array" element to be able to be treated as an array when you retrieve the data.

Just to be mentioned, if you need to make some queries when you retrieve the data (for example, how many users assist to a specific party) consider to flatten your structure data like this:

[image: flat database structure]

With this you can be able to query, for example, all the users that have a specific partyId. For more information, you can check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data) to create good data structures